# Let $f(x)=x^2+6x+6$ . Problem from a local math competition, wasn't provided a solution. Would be great if somebody could help me out here.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

Let $f(x)=x^2+6x+6$. Let $r$ be the difference between the largest and smallest real solutions of $f(f(f(x)))=0$. Then $r=a\times c^{\frac {1} {b}}$ for some positive integers $a$, $b$, $c$, such that $c$ is a minimum. Compute $a+b+c$.

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  It is **irrelevant** whether the problem is homework.  What counts is whether the protocol is observed.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please let us know what you have tried so that we can better help you.

Comment: Hello @ÁtilaCorreia . I first tried by finding the inverse function of $f(x)$, which I denoted $g(x)$. I found $g(x)$ to be $-3 \pm \sqrt {(3-x)}$. I then took the inverse three times, but my answer was not of the form the question says. Therefore, I am consulting this website.

Comment: @kyokutan Could you please put your attempt in the body of the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach: the outer $f$ can be thought of as $f(x) = 0$ to which we simply get

$$ x^2 + 6x + 6 = 0 \implies x^2 + 6x + 9 = 3 \implies (x+3)^2 = 3 \implies x = -3 \pm 3^{\frac{1}{2}}. $$

Then that means the middle $f$ can be thought of as $f(x) = -3 \pm 3^{\frac{1}{2}}$ to which we get

$$ x^2 + 6x + 6 = -3 \pm 3^{\frac{1}{2}} \implies (x + 3)^2 = \pm 3^{\frac{1}{2}} \implies x = -3 \pm 3^{\frac{1}{4}}. $$

We only consider real solutions so we can ignore the negative under square root.

Finally we have the inner $f$ which can be thought of as $f(x) = -3 \pm 3^{\frac{1}{4}}$ to which we get

$$ x^2 + 6x + 6 = -3 \pm 3^{\frac{1}{4}} \implies x = -3 \pm 3^{\frac{1}{8}}. $$

The values under the square root have to be positive for real solutions. So the real solutions are

$$ x_L = -3 + 3^{\frac{1}{8}}, \quad x_S = -3 - 3^{\frac{1}{8}}. $$

The difference is $2 \cdot 3^{\frac{1}{8}}$.

Comment: Your answer is a good answer, but for future reference, I advise you to not to answer questions like this one that show little work and offer no context. Such questions are against the [site guidelines](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) and are likely to be closed. Furthermore, answering these sorts of questions is in general against [site policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards); many users consider it bad for the site as a whole, and may sometimes even downvote such answers.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

I would recommend you to notice that:

\begin{align*}
f(x) = x^{2} + 6x + 6 = (x + 3)^{2} - 3 & \Rightarrow f(f(x)) = (x + 3)^{4} - 3\\\\
& \Rightarrow f(f(f(x))) = (x + 3)^{8} - 3
\end{align*}

In general, $f^{(n)}(x) = (x + 3)^{2^{n}} - 3$.

Based on it, can you proceed?